# ios, Youtube full screen in a webview is rotating

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube, fullscreen, landscape-portrait

I am developing and app which i want a youtube video in a page.
It works fine withe the code below:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.47 green:.43 blue:.4 alpha:1];

}

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    NSString *htmlString;
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 20\"/></head><body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"768\" height=\"960\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"768\" height=\"960\"></embed></object></div></body></html>",urlToOpen,urlToOpen];

    }else{
        htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head><body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"1024\" height=\"704\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"1024\" height=\"704\"></embed></object></div></body></html>",urlToOpen,urlToOpen];

    }
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];
    return  YES;
}
```

The view is working fine in portrait and in landscape.
The problem is when i see the video with the full Screen and i Rotate. Whe i finish the full screen, the webview didn't detect the rotation and print the webview as the wrong way.

How could i detect the Youtube full screen is rotating for rotate my view?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set content width to 100%

my template

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"> \
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> <head> \
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=320\"> \
<style> \
html,body {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; size:100%%} \
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;width:100%;} \
table { font-family:Georgia; font-size:%dpt; border-style: none; size:100%%} \
</style> </head>
```

....

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming your already handling the orientation callbacks? (shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation)

When the YouTube video finishes and focus is returned to your app, the viewWillAppear method should be called.  In there, you can get the device orientation:

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
```

Then perform your layout changes.  This also would handle the layout when this view first opens.

You could do it in a switch statement:

```
switch(orientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:  //layout for this landscape mode
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:  //layout for this portrait mode
```

Comment: Thnks but it is nor really correct. The youtube full screen is when the user push the two arrows that makes the video as big as the screen. Then, when you rotate with this full screen and push "done", the screen keeps with the original orientation. viewWillAppear is not called.

Answer (score -1):

I handled that problem using NSNotification like this

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidExitFullScreen)
                                             name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

and method that will be called is

```
- (void)moviePlayerDidExitFullScreen
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    }
}
```

Hope that Helps

Comment: Private API usage may break your app or cause rejection.

Comment: Private API ? can you see any private api usage above ?

Comment: UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification is not documented anywhere. So, it could be changed in OS update... Also, using undocumented notification could cause rejection.

Comment: My application is working Live on appstore, By the way if you have better way do let me know ?

Comment: does this work?? is it or not a private API?? thanks